# Создание двухмерного динамического массива в СИ

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Не могу создать двухмерный динамический массив в СИ(не++),помогите примером.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int x = 10, y = 20; 
int ** array = (int**) malloc (sizeof (int*) * x); 
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
  array [i] = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int)*y); 
}
```

Comment: [Нет необходимости](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) кастовать значение, возвращаемое `malloc`ом